# How to get a Sample Standard Deviation values that match condition?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to get the standard deviation of a subset of data. I have two sheets

```
Name Value
a    1
a    2
a    1
b    5
b    5
```

In a separate sheet I have:

```
Name StdDev
a   
b
```

GOAL: I am trying to get:

```
Name StdDev
a    .57
b    0
```

I tried:

```
=query('Sheet1'!A1:B999,"select STDEV(B) where A='"&A1&"'")
```

Error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 13. Was expecting one of:  "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ... "," ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "/" ... "%" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "+" ... "-" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first of all, there is no **`STDEV(Col)`** parameter in Google Sheets' **`QUERY`** so you need to create it from:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

```
=SQRT(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA((QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:$B}, "select Col2 where Col1='"&D2&"'")-
 AVERAGE(QUERY({Sheet1!$A$2:$B}, "where Col1='"&D2&"'")))^2))/
 (COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A, "="&D2)-1))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

**shorter alternative:**

- **cell D2: `=UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A)`**
- **cell E2: `=STDEV(FILTER(Sheet1!B:B, Sheet1!A:A=D2))`**
- **cell E3: `=STDEV(FILTER(Sheet1!B:B, Sheet1!A:A=D3))`**

  [image]